# ArcGIS JS API: Zooming with mouse wheel/double-click forces pan

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, jquery

I have a map that I'm initializing off-screen and sliding in using jQuery. For some reason zooming in with the scroll wheel or by double-clicking causes the map to simultaneously pan down (or pan up when zooming out). Using the slider controls works fine. Also if I disable the animation and create it on-screen it zooms normally. I'm guessing it has something to do with the relative position of the map to where it was created, but I don't imagine I have much control over that. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Here's how I'm styling the map:

`#map {
    bottom: -450px;
    height: 450px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}`

And this is my animation function:

```
toggleMap: function() {
    // New bottom value
    var newBottom;

    if (isShowing) {
        newBottom = -450px;
    }
    else {
        newBottom = 0;
    }

    isShowing = !isShowing;
    $map.animate({
        bottom: newBottom
    });
},
```

Comment: I've had the same issue with using dojo.fx to move the map in from the right or left. The map pans right or left as I zoom in and out with the scroll wheel.

Comment: Interesting... sounds like an under-the-hood problem with the API to me. Like its calculating the cursor position based on the starting point of the map. Anybody from Esri listening? :)

Comment: If you post a full repro case I can take a look (I work on the JS API team at esri). One thing to make sure you're doing is calling map.reposition after you move the map's div:  https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#reposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you move the map's element (probably a div), call [map.reposition()](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#reposition).